# How to fix error installing psutil on Windows 10?

Tags: python, installation

every time i try to install psutil in command prompt for python through "pip install psutil" command it gives me this error message:

```
Complete output (38 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.10
    creating build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psaix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psosx.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psposix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil
    creating build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\runner.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_aix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_bsd.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_contracts.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_linux.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_memleaks.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_osx.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_process.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_sunos.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_system.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_testutils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_windows.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\psutil\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_windows' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\windows 10 pro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\windows 10 pro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-freyn2_2\\psutil_d40b23d5499d4943a851ba2d31c42b65\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\windows 10 pro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-freyn2_2\\psutil_d40b23d5499d4943a851ba2d31c42b65\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\windows 10 pro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8dc_d_jb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\windows 10 pro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Include\psutil' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Could anyone please help me with this?
So i can finally edit and run .py file

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with version 5.9.3 to avoid this error

```
pip install psutil==5.9.3
```

see here:
https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/2165

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the error log, you need to install the compiler from the link presented to you because a package you're trying to install requires a compiler due to accessing Win32 API (a C/C++ library) in a way that utilized C/C++/Cython or other compiled code i.e. a Python Extension unlike other pure-Python packages that only require a specific Python version, implementation or bitness.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/